# How can I give a large audience access to a SharePoint task list without giving them access to the rest of what's on the site?

Tags: list, permissions, task-list

Our department has a department site as part of our larger company SharePoint site. We've created a task list on the department site, and we want a large group of people from multiple departments to be able to view and add tasks to the list, but without giving them access to anything else on our site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Uninherit the list
2. Give access to whoever needs it. If it's a large group I suggest using an AD security group.
3. Give them the direct link or post the link elsewhere that they can navigate to it. They will not be able to navigate to the site that it's hosted on.